# Which was the comic in which Wonder Woman got married to a green alien/creature?

Tags: dc, comics, episode-identification, wonder-woman

I saw a Wonder Woman comic cover once, but can't remember which one.
It had Wonder Woman getting married to some green alien dude or something on it.
Did she really got married in it or was it just for the cover ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is [Wonder Woman #155](http://comicvine.gamespot.com/wonder-woman-155-i-married-a-monster/4000-109209/) "*I Married a Monster!*" in which Wonder Woman is depicted (on the cover) marrying ***Mr. Monster***

[image]

She was *genuinely* persuaded to marry him after he defies the Amazonian Army and shields her from falling rubble with his own body, proving his worthiness as a potential husband.

[image]

But eventually he ends up...

> .... ditching her at the altar
>  [image]

Comment: After seeing this answer I had a vision of Leela and Alcazar in the "A Bicyclops Built for Two" Futurama episode.

Comment: I think this was referenced in the recent "Sugar and Spike Investigations" series in LEGENDS OF TOMORROW.

Comment: Perhaps the *real* Mr. Monster is the prejudices of society.

Comment: @RogueJedi - I assumed it was a sexual allegory.

Comment: Bro got low self-esteem.